# QEMU -display gtk and -display sdl not available | Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: gtk, qemu

Starting a VM with `qemu-system-x86_64 (...) -display gtk` produces error `Display 'gtk' not available`. This is a standard desktop installation (i. e. no modifications to qemu version).

How do I get QEMU to start the VM in a GTK window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the package `qemu-system-gui` contains `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qemu/ui-gtk.so` and should - once installed enable the `-display gtk` feature.